# Dummy indices and constraints in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, indices

I would like that Mathematica simplifies an expression according to some constraints. For example:

```
M = p.k p.k
```

given the constraint:

```
p(mu) * p(nu) = \delta(mu,nu)
```

should give

```
M = k^2
```

But I don't know how to specify dummy indices, and I am also not quite sure where I should place the constraint itself. In an argument of Simplify?

Comment: Many builtin functions (e.g. `Simplify`) support the `Assumptions` option for specifying constraints.

Comment: Can you explain your notations or otherwise use standard Mathematica notation?

Comment: The dot means the dot product. p(mu) means p at index mu (p and k are vectors), the delta is the Kronecker delta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In[1]:= FilePrint["dummyindices.m"]
<<HighEnergyPhysics`FeynCalc`
Print[" "];
{$AL[1], $AL[2]} = {mu, nu};  (* $AL are predefined dummy indices *)
M = SP[p,k] * SP[p,k];        (* this defines p.k * p.k *)
SP[k, k] = k2;                (* abbreviate the scalar product k^2 by k2 *)
constraint = FeynCalcInternal[ 
               FourVector[p,mu] FourVector[p,nu] -> MetricTensor[mu, nu] 
];       (* this is one way of specifying the constraint *)
(* use the Uncontract function http://www.feyncalc.org/FeynCalcBook/Uncontract/*)
Print["uncontracting : ", FCF[ tmp = Uncontract[M, k, Pair->All, Unique->False]]];
Print["contract and using the constraint : ",
       FeynCalcExternal @ Contract[tmp /. constraint]
]

In[2]:= <<dummyindices.m
Loading FeynCalc from /home/rolfm/HighEnergyPhysics
FeynCalc 8.1.0 Type ?FeynCalc for help or visit http://www.feyncalc.org/
$PrePrint is set to FeynCalcForm. Use FI and FC to change the display format.
Loading FeynArts, see www.feynarts.de for documentation
FeynArts 3.4 patched for use with FeynCalc

uncontracting :  k[mu] k[nu] p[mu] p[nu]
contract and using the constraint : k2
```